# Swipe gesture on SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer, skspritenode

I have a `spriteNode` where I need to have swipe detection on a `SKSpriteNode`, but it seems that swipe gesture can only do on view. Is there a way to do this?

```
SKSpriteNode *rabbit = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rabbit_img"];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self   action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the starting coordinates of the swipe via the `state` [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
- (void)swipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer view]];
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        NSLog(@"start coordinates: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
}
```

You can then compare those coordinates against your desired nodes using the SKNode method `containsPoint:` to see if the swipe originated from a node.